# How to download Hadoop files (on HDFS) via FTP?

Tags: hadoop, ssis, hdfs, bigdata

I would like to implement an SSIS job that is able to download large CSV files that are located on a remote Hadoop cluster. Of course, having just a regular FTP server on Hadoop system does not expose HDFS files since it uses the local filesystem.

I would like to know whether there is an FTP server implementation that sits on top of HDFS. I would prefer this approach rather than having to copy files from HDFS to the local FS and then having the FTP server serving this because I will need to allocate more storage space.

Comment: One option is to install fuse. This will mount HDFS to a local directory and then you just need to perform local FS to FTP file transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked from an open-source project that works as expected: https://github.com/jamesattard/maroodi